# Выделение дробной части из double

Tags: java, double

Я сделал по топорному,

```
double d= Double.valueOf("5.0596");
int i= (int) d; 
double d2= d- i; // дробная часть
```

как можно по другому сделать?

Comment: А d%1 не выделит ли дробную часть? В Питоне точно работает :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044079/separating-double-into-integer-and-decimal-parts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как уже посоветовали, `d%1` выполняет ровно то, что надо, наиболее синтаксически коротким методом. С другой стороны, не обязательно это самый дешёвый в вычислении метод; Ваш "топорный" метод в этом смысле может быть даже лучше; если важна скорость, то лучше сделать бенчмарк по сравнению с вычитанием целой части.

Учтите, что int может не вместить всех целых значений для double в тех пределах, где double представляет все целые числа. Для long такое есть хотя бы для диапазона, где шаг значений double равен 1 или меньше. И конверсия бо́льших значений работает так, что молча выдаёт соответствующее крайнее целое, так что результат надо проверять.